# python getopt module raise error when argument is not behind an option

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, getopt

I have the a piece of code to handle command line arguments.

```
def parse_cmd_args():
    input_path = None
    output_name = 'out.flv.txt'
    is_detail = False
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hi:o:d")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'Usage:'
        print 'parse_flv -i input_path -o [output_name]'
        sys.exit()
    for op, value in opts:
        if op == '-i':
            input_path = value
        elif op == '-o':
            output_name = value
        elif op == '-d':
            is_detail = True
        elif op == '-h':
            print 'Usage:'
            print 'parse_flv -i input_path [-o output_name]'
            sys.exit()
    return os.path.abspath(input_path), output_name, is_detail
```

If I input a command `without a option symbol '-'` like this:

```
 python parse_flv.py s
```

It will raise an error.

**MY QUESTION**:

How to handle arguments without a '-i' like option using getopt module. Thanks

Comment: It's worrying that you have the usage message printed in two places and that the messages are different (and both are incomplete since neither mentions `-h` or `-d`).  Please use a function for the job (and then you can write to standard error instead of standard output, too).  You code does not appear to enforce the mandatory `-i` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module instead. `getopt` is kind of limited...

This module is a lot more handy (less code and more informative help and error messages). In your case this would simply be something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs=1, help='input file name')
parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', help='output file name')
```

In this example, `outfile` would be optional and you could specify a default output file name:

```
parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', help='output file name', default='out.txt')
```

More details about both `getopt` and `argparse` [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-command-line-arguments-argv-example/) (compared to each other).

---

**EDIT :**

Here is the best one can do with `getopt` (as far as I read), i.e. switch to `GNU mode` using `gnu_getopt`:

```
import getopt
import sys

output_name = 'out.txt'
input_name = ''

print 'ARGV      :', sys.argv[1:]

options, remainder = getopt.gnu_getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'o:', ['input-path',
                                                           'output-name=',
                                                          ])
print 'OPTIONS   :', options

for opt, arg in options:
    if opt in ('-o', '--output-name'):
        output_name = arg
    else: 
        pass

# Get input name by yourself...
input_name = remainder[0]

print 'OUTPUTNAME  :', output_name
print 'REMAINING   :', remainder
print 'INPUTNAME   :', input_name
```

Calling:

```
python parse_flv.py input -o output
```

or

```
python parse_flv.py -o output input
```

outputs:

```
ARGV      : ['-o', 'output', 'input']
OPTIONS   : [('-o', 'output')]
OUTPUTNAME  : output
REMAINING   : ['input']
INPUTNAME   : input
```

which would confirm that you then have to deal with the `remaining` list by yourself...

But, at least, you can switch the order of the two options.

**Interesting source [here](http://pymotw.com/2/getopt/).**

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the argument `s` is in the list `args` returned from `getopt.getopt()`.